# For loop won't give to right answer

Tags: python

My problem is that I want to change õ,ö,ä,ü ( characters used in my language ) with oe, ae, ue. I import the file with text in it: `Ööülikooli siserännak` (it's just an example ), and I want to get back `OEOEUELIKOOLI SISERAENNAK`.

My code looks like this:

```
failname = input("Insert the fail name: ")
fail = open(failname, encoding = "UTF-8")

for line in fail:
    if char == "õ":
        print("oe".upper(), end = "")
    elif char == "ö":
        print("oe".upper(), end = "")
    elif char == "ä":
        print("ae".upper(), end = "")
    elif char == "ü":
        print("ue".upper(), end = "")
    else:
        print(char.upper(), end = "")
```

and the result is:

```
   Insert the fail name: example.txt
   ÖOEUELIKOOLI SISERAENNAK
```

So my question is, why the first character won't change? I have tried it with other examples too, but always the first one remains same.

Comment: `Ö` != `ö`, that's why. Also, please show us *actual* code. What is `char`?!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try to use it:

```
failname = input("Insert the fail name: ")
fail = open(failname, encoding = "UTF-8")

for line in fail: 
    for char in line:
        if char.lower() == "õ":
            print("oe".upper(), end = "")
        elif char.lower() == "ö":
            print("oe".upper(), end = "")
        elif char.lower() == "ä":
            print("ae".upper(), end = "")
        elif char.lower() == "ü":
            print("ue".upper(), end = "")
        else:
            print(char.upper(), end = "")
    print("\n")
```

Answer (score 1):

Replace the comparison with this instead:

```
if char.lower() == "ö"
```

You can update the others also, so you can replace both lower and upper cases

**Caveat**: `char` variable appears to be undefined

Answer (score 0):

I don't think Ö and ö are the same character, just like A and a have different ascii value Ö and ö have different utf-8 value try adding

```
if char == 'Ö':
   # what you want to change it to
```

Answer (score 0):

Next time, make sure to show your code as a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). It contains lots of small and larger errors, and the entire reading-from-a-file part, for example, is not relevant to your question. Also think of a more descriptive title.

---

Rather than deciding on one character at a time with lots of `if`s, do the following:

```
string = "Ööülikooli siserännak"
string = string.upper()

for find,replace in [['Ö','OE'], ['Ü', 'UE'], ['Ä', 'AE']]:
   string = string.replace (find,replace)

print (string)
```

This way you can easily add more character pairs as the need arises. Note that I do an `upper()` as the first step, so you only have to check capitals – which is something you forgot in your code.